# Ruby client and Python server not receiving the full message while exchanging

Tags: python, ruby, client-server

I am trying to establish a client-server communication. The client is written in Ruby whereas the server is written in Python.

**client.rb**

```
require 'socket'

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 7778

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
s.write("2020-06-25T11:11:00+00:00 5  127.0.0.1 printer: event")


while line = s.gets
puts line.chop
end

s.close()
```

The ruby client sends a log to the Python server and tries to receive it back.
**server.py**

```
import socket

#Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#bind the socket to the port - tuple
server_address = ('localhost', 7778)
print('starting up on %s port %s' %server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
#Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
   print('waiting for a connection')
   connection, client_address = sock.accept()
   while True:
      data = connection.recv(1024)
      print('received "%s"' % data)
      if data:
         print('sending data back to the client')
         connection.send(data)
      else:
         print('no more data from', client_address)
         break
   connection.close()
```

The log is sent to the python server and when the python server sends it back. When the ruby client receives it, it doesn't receive the full log.
example:

```
2020-06-25T11:11:00+00:00 5  127.0.0.1 printer: eve
```

I think this comes from the fact that TCP is a streaming protocol and we never know if we can get the full message each time.

Could you propose me a solution for both the client and the server so I can be sure they always receive the full message between each other? I would really appreciate it if anyone would help.

Comment: You mean like `HTTP`?

Comment: Like @max mentioned HTTP is what you are looking for. But if it they both are on the same machine i'd also suggest RabbitMQ


https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: `the fact that TCP is a streaming protocol` I think you're thinking of `UDP`. TCP is a stream protocol as it is considered to be a stream of data delivered in order it was sent. So long as the connection is open and a valid path exists, it is guaranteed that it will be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you're assuming the data received has a new line character - however the data you're sending is not terminated by a new line.

`s.write("2020-06-25T11:11:00+00:00 5  127.0.0.1 printer: event")` will not write the string with a new line character - you should use `puts` [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-puts)

`s.gets` will return the data because the socket is closed by the python server after it has sent the data. So even `gets`says it will read the next line from the socket, in reality its just reading what remained in the buffer after the socket was closed.

`line.chop` will remove the last character, and you're using it here to strip a newline character (assuming that it has one from `gets`). However since there is no newline character it will remove the last character instead.

So the fix would be to replace in the ruby client `s.write` with `s.puts`.